# air 2.0 on application quit, call preventDefault

Tags: apache-flex, air

Trying to prevent the application from shutting down when clicked the `X` button, it still closing but the AIR process is running in the task manager. What wrong with the code?

Application Complete:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.EXITING, onExiting);
```

Closing code:

```
private function onExiting(e:Event):void
{
e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Event.CLOSING`. That's what I use to cancel closing.

`Event.EXITING` happens after the window is removed and should be used only for cleanup, and not to prevent the application from closing.

From the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=app_launch_1.html):

> On Windows, the only time you will get
>   the exiting event is after closing the
>   last window (when autoExit=true).

---

Sample "unclosable" application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       initialize="init()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            private function init():void{
                this.addEventListener(Event.CLOSING, function(e:Event):void{
                    e.preventDefault();
                    Alert.show('Unclosable!');
                });
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Good luck,
Alin

Comment: erm, it will still close even when I change to your solution. On Windows 7.

Comment: It works in Windows 7 too. I'm using the exact same thing in an application to ask for save when the user wants to close the window from the x button. Are you using `Event.CLOSING`, and not `Event.CLOSE`?

Comment: I use Closing, maybe could you post a sample code? Appreciate.

Comment: Thank you, at least this way work. I saw someone having issue with closing probably on 64bit? The "function" make it easy to implement a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Alert message processing happens in different thread than application thread so application do not wait for alert message box. The trick is to have a global variable with initialized value of false. On event handler for close, cancel close event if value is not changed to true. This allows alert message to show up. If user pressed Yes then set the variable to true and again fire exit function.

```
        private var boolExit:Boolean=false;

        private function alertClickHandler(event:CloseEvent):void{
            if(event.detail==Alert.YES){
                boolExit=true;
                NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
            }

        }


        private function AppExit(e:Event):void{
            if(!boolExit)
                e.preventDefault();

            Alert.show("Do you want to exit application?",
                "Exit Confirmation",
                Alert.YES|Alert.NO,null,
                alertClickHandler
                );
        }

        public function init():void
        {
           . . . 
           this.addEventListener(Event.CLOSING,AppExit);
           . . .
        }
```